# how can one integrate dateRangeInput to two layred ggplot with a filter function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, shiny, magrittr

I want to integrate the dateRangeInput in this case?

The goal is to select a date range so the both geom_bar can react to my input.

this is the data that i work on :
( https://impfdashboard.de/static/data/germany_deliveries_timeseries_v2.tsv )

```
library(readr)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

ui <- basicPage(

  # first-input
  selectInput(
    inputId = "sel22",  label = "Möglichkeitfür Histogramm (2)  auswählen",
       list("dosen_biontech_kumulativ","dosen_kumulativ","dosen_biontech_erst_kumulativ")
  ),

  # second-input
  selectInput(inputId = "sel2",  label = "Möglichkeit für Histogramm (1) auswählen",
       list("dosen_kumulativ","dosen_biontech_kumulativ","dosen_biontech_erst_kumulativ")
  ),
 
  # outpot
  plotOutput("plot"),
dateRangeInput("daterange", "Date range:",
               start  = "2020-12-29",
               end    = "2021-12-09",
               min    = "2020-12-28",
               max    = "2021-12-08",
               format = "mm/dd/yy",
               separator = " - "),
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Summarize Data and then Plot
  data2 <- reactive({
req(input$sel2)
lf <- germany_vaccinations_timeseries_v2 %>%  group_by(date ) %>% summarise( output = get(input$sel2))
})

datao2 <- reactive({
req(input$sel22)
lf <- germany_vaccinations_timeseries_v2 %>%  group_by(date ) %>% summarise( output = get(input$sel22))
})

output$plot2 <- renderPlot({  

ggplot() +
geom_bar(data = data2(), aes(y = output, x = date), stat = "sum")+
geom_bar(data = datao2(), aes( y = output,x = date), stat = "sum")+
theme(legend.position = "none" ) +  labs(y= "Anzahl der Dosen", x = "Datum")

})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What is the expected output? I didn't understand what `dosen_kumulativ","dosen_biontech_kumulativ....` are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it.

The first thing you need to see is the `date` column in your `df` is of class `date` and not `character`.

```
germany_vaccinations_timeseries_v2$date <- as.Date(germany_vaccinations_timeseries_v2$date, 
                                                   format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

The next thing I found wrong in the code is the labels you have used for `selectInput`. You need to specify them to match the columns from your `df`.

Here's how it should look like:

```
selectInput(
    inputId = "sel22",  label = "Möglichkeitfür Histogramm (2)  auswählen",
    list("impfstoff", "region", "dosen", "einrichtung")
    #list("dosen_biontech_kumulativ","dosen_kumulativ","dosen_biontech_erst_kumulativ")
  ),
  
  # second-input
  selectInput(inputId = "sel2",  label = "Möglichkeit für Histogramm (1) auswählen",
              list("impfstoff", "region", "dosen", "einrichtung")
              #list("dosen_kumulativ","dosen_biontech_kumulativ","dosen_biontech_erst_kumulativ")
  )
```

The whole code for `ui` is as follows:

```
ui <- basicPage(
  # first-input
  selectInput(
    inputId = "sel22",  label = "Möglichkeitfür Histogramm (2)  auswählen",
    list("impfstoff", "region", "dosen", "einrichtung")
    #list("dosen_biontech_kumulativ","dosen_kumulativ","dosen_biontech_erst_kumulativ")
  ),
  
  # second-input
  selectInput(inputId = "sel2",  label = "Möglichkeit für Histogramm (1) auswählen",
              list("impfstoff", "region", "dosen", "einrichtung")
              #list("dosen_kumulativ","dosen_biontech_kumulativ","dosen_biontech_erst_kumulativ")
  ),
  
  dateRangeInput(inputId = "date", "Date range:",
                 start  = "2020-12-29",
                 end    = "2021-02-20",
                 min    = "2020-12-28",
                 max    = "2021-12-08",
                 separator = " - "),
  
  # outpot
  plotOutput("plot")
)
```

In order to get `dateRangeInput` from user, you can use `filter` like this:

```
df <- reactive({
    filter(germany_vaccinations_timeseries_v2, between(date, input$date[1], input$date[2]))  
  })
```

The whole code for the server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Summarize Data and then Plot
    
  df <- reactive({
    filter(germany_vaccinations_timeseries_v2, between(date, input$date[1], input$date[2]))  
  })
  
  data2 <- reactive({
    req(input$sel2)
    lf <- df() %>%  group_by(date) %>% summarise(output = get(input$sel2))
  })
  
  datao2 <- reactive({
    req(input$sel22)
    lf <- df() %>%  group_by(date) %>% summarise(output = get(input$sel22))
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({  
     ggplot() +
      geom_bar(data = data2(), aes(y = output, x = date), stat = "sum")+
      #geom_bar(data = datao2(), aes( y = output,x = date), stat = "sum")+
      theme(legend.position = "none" ) +  labs(y= "Anzahl der Dosen", x = "Datum")
  })
}
```

I didn't understand why you have two `geom_bar` in your code. You can plot it separately with another `plotOutput` and using the same date range there as well.